# Unable to run memtest from grub boot menu

Tags: 12.04, memtest

12.04 LTS running along with Windows 8(dual boot). My problem is when I try to run memtest from grub boot menu I get this error

> too small lower memory (0x99100 > 0x98400)

I have 1 GB of RAM and 80 GB HDD. Ubuntu runs on dedicated 12 GB partition with 2 GB swap space. Why am I getting this error and how to troubleshoot this error. Please provide step by step tips.

Answer (score 0):

as I have seen , this problem was effected many users .

as I came to know one solution is there with installing other version .

get this file download

```
wget http://www.memtest.org/download/4.20/memtest86+-4.20.zip
```

unzip that and there exists a .bin file .

execute with

```
chmod +x <filename>.bin
./<filename>.bin
```

hope it helps you .

Comment: Are you suggesting to replace version with one you suggest?.

Comment: @upsla yes .I am suggesting that .